# Using same models for different webpages

Tags: python, django, forms, model

So I have a Topic.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    topic_choices = (
                    ('t_topic', 't_topic',),
                    ('f_topic', 'f_topic',)
    )
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=topic_choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

The topic is retrieved and displayed based on the date it was created.

```
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics """
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

What I would like to do is to have the Topic somehow distinguished based on which web page it was created from.

And then I want the same topic to be displayed on the same webpage.

As you can see here, below. The same topic is displayed on topic.html and f_topic.html because the same topic_id is used.

I want to have it so that if the topic was created on topic.html then it is displayed on topic.html. If it is created on f_topic.html then it is displayed on f_topic.html.

```
def topic(request, topic_id, type):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id, type='t_topic')
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    images = Image.objects.filter(imgtopic__in=entries)
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries, 'images': images}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

def f_topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id = topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    images = Image.objects.filter(imgtopic__in = entries)
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries, 'images': images}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/f_topic.html', context)
```

How the topic is saved as t_type

```
def new_topic(request):

    if request.method != 'POST':
    #No data submitted; create a blank form.
    form = TopicForm()

        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit = False)
            new_topic.type = 't_topic'
            new_topic.owner = request.user 
            new_topic.save() 
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))
    else:
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)'
```

topic.html

```
 {% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

 {% block content %}
    <div class = 'topic-heading'>
     <p>TOPIC : {{topic}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class = 'topic-container'> 
     {%include 'learning_logs/text.html'%}
    </div>
```

I get the same error of NoReverseMatch at /topics/
Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '(10, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[^/]+)/$']

Here is the topics.html that should display the topics.

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class = 'topics-1'>
    <h1> Topics: </h1>

    <ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
        <li>
         <a href = "{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id topic.type%}">[] {{topic}}</a>
        </li>

        {% empty %}

        <li> No topics have been added yet. </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

<a href = "{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}"> Add a new topic :</a>
```

{% endblock content %}

Comment: What problem are you running into now? You should also post your html for topic pages.

Comment: Same error NoReverseMatch at /topics/
Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '(10, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<type>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: When is that error showing? When you try to visit topic.html? What is the link you are clicking on when you go to the page that shows the error? Are you sure the object in question has a type saved in the db?

Comment: The error occurs when I just want the topics to be displayed. So if I create a topic, it should be listed on a template called topics.html. and then if a click on a specific topic, a new template should open called topic.html, and its contents should be displayed there. I am not exactly to sure how to check the database, I am assuming through shell right?

Comment: so it is stored in the data base  ..     print(topic.id, topic, topic.type)
...
1 John Connor t_topic
9 Simple t_topic
10 New One
11 john
12 kkkkk
13 oiojoijioj
14 ppppppp
15 pppoko t_topic
16 plplplplp t_topic
17 okokook t_topic
18 gucci t_topic
19 pkpkpkppk t_topic
20 okokokokokokpopopopo t_topic
21 kokokokok t_topic
22 okkoko t_topic

Comment: Why are my edits getting rejected? You can use the shell, connect to db from cl, or you should look into psequel. Good tool to visualize things quickly. Don't know what db you are using though. Basically your problem as I understand it is that you are not passing the topic.type to the url so it cannot match.

Comment: It looks like you have them saved with a type so you just have to pass that type to the url when you are requesting a page, whether from a link or from a redirect.

Comment: my bad, I don't know how this site works. I'll approve the edits.  It seems like I had some previous topics that didn't have types at all and so nothing was being passed at all. I deleted all the topics and now it seems to be working. Thanks, ill get back to you once I set everything up, just to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a type to your Topic model i.e.:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
topic_choices= (
                ('t_topic', 't_topic',)
                ('f_topic', 'f_topic',)
)
text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=topic_choices)

def __str__(self):

    return self.text
```

and then when you retrieve the topics specify the type:

```
def f_topic(request, topic_id, type):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id, type='f_topic')
```

You would have to change your urls, but you can add it to the link:

```
<a href = "{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id topic.type %}">
```

Comment: How do I pass on the the type to the f_topic function?

Comment: The topic.id is passed on through another template to the f_topic function. Such as <a href = "{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">[] {{topic}}</a>. Now I get the error saying that type positional argument is missing.

Comment: @h.pylori - forgot to tell you I updated my answer. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Do I need add anything to the urls.py? This is what it looks like right [path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name = 'topic'),]

Comment: @h.pylori - yes you have to add the type [path('topics/<int:topic_id>/<type>/', views.topic, name = 'topic'),] It would help to know what error you are getting or where things are going wrong.

Comment: Right now I am getting [Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '(10, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<type>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: We do not really have a form or a function that tells whether the data should be stored in f_type or t_type. Am I missing something here? So  how it know where it should be stored

Comment: Yeah so for some reason the type is not getting passed. You can put the logic in your view that says if a topic was created on f_topic html, then it is type f_topic, object.save(). Do the same for just plain topic. I'm assuming you have a view for topics created on f_topic, and a different view for topics created on topic?

Comment: yes, I do. [new_topic.save('t_topic')] is that suppose to work? For now, I want to it to be that so that any topic that is created is stored on t_topic, but it I still get the same error.

Comment: But are you specifying the type before you save? In other words, new_topic.type = 't_topic', and then save. Check your database tables and make sure your objects have values for the type attribute. If they don't then you can't use them.

Answer (score 0):

To make this possible, add to context the name of the template.

```
context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries, 'images': images, 'template':example.html}
```

Then in the model topic, add a field :

```
template = models.CharField(max_length = 200).
```

In the view where you save newly created topics, get the request value of template :

```
topic.template = request.POST.get("template")
```